# How do I configure an npm module so that it's exports are always imported from the libraries root?

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, intellisense

1. I have written a library published as an npm module
2. When a user installs the module, and then tries to use VSCode's IntelliSense to auto import functions from it, IntelliSense write the import line with a file path all the way to where the function is defined- deep inside the file-folder structure of my library
3. I would prefer that it import the function from where it is exported in the root file of the module, so that if multiple functions are imported from the library, all of the imports are expressed in a single line of the users code.

Thank you for reading, any advice on how to fix or where to start researching would be much appreciated. Have a blessed day!